# How to place a longitude variable into a NSURL?

Tags: iphone, geolocation, nsurl

I have 2 variables which contain long and latitude data. I want to open a quite long url using these.

The url looks something this:
http://something.com/infok/infocontent.php?xcoord=47.666666&ycoord=19.666666&p=1&utInf=1&kezeloInf=1&coordInf=1&utkatInf=1&anfInf=1&dijasIn=1&teliInf=1&utInf=1&utInf=1

So I want to change the numbers after `xcoord=` and `ycoord=` sections with my variables.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
double xcoord = ...., ycoord = ....  ;
NSURL* url = [[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString 
    stringWithFormat:@"http://something.com/infok/infocontent.php?xcoord=%f&ycoord=%f&p=1&utInf....", xcoord, ycoord]]];
```

Comment: A NSString should use the %@ type specifier, a C string should use the %s specifier. The %d is used for integers.